# Primefaces' Datatable pagination is not working fine with filtered values

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, pagination

I am using `JSF 2.0` with with `PrimeFaces 5.2` in my Web Application. On a page there is a `Datatable` wich shows Tickets stored in `Database` in paginated form.
Normally `pagination` is working fine but when I filter the Tickets using `filterBy`, it returns 4 pages, in which first page shows correctly filtered Ticktes, as soon as I click on page 2 or any page number greater than 1, the `Datatable` does not show filtered results rather it shows the unfiltered tickets of respective page as if no filter was applied, I want filtered results on other pages also .

More precisely I want that when I click on a page number greater than 1 , `Datatable` fetch respective page from the set of filtered tickets not form the set of all the Tickets. How can I do this?

I have gone through `PrimeFaces 5.2'` User-Guide , and read the attributes of the Datatable and tried a few which seemed helpful but problem still remains.

here is my Datatable,

```
<p:dataTable id="tickets" var="ticket"
                value="#{ticketBean.ticketModels}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                filteredValue="#{ticketBean.filteredTickets}">



                <p:column headerText="Summary" style="width:300px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ticket.summary}" />
                </p:column>



                <p:column headerText="Status" filterBy="#{ticket.status}"
                    filterOptions="#{ticketBean.statusFilterList}"
                    filterMatchMode="exact" style="width:110px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ticket.status}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Assigned To" filterBy="#{ticket.assignedTo}"
                    filterOptions="#{ticketBean.userFilterList}" filterMatchMode="exact"
                    style="width:110px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{ticket.assignedTo}" />
                </p:column>
    ....................................
            </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Show some code please. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) on how to create an mcve

Answer (score -1):

Just add the below line to your p:datatable and check the same

```
paginator="true" rows="10" 
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} 
{PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}
{NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} " 
rowsPerPageTemplate="10,15,20"
```

Comment: i tried ,its still not working . By the way, What is the idea behind adding these attributes ? @user1433804

Comment: @AlokMishra it adds a customized paginator with 10 rows per page to your `p:dataTable` tag. And yes, that does not solve the problem. I'm facing same here. And other person has same issue, maybe mark one as duplicate?